# Change value of DOM element by Javascript loop

Tags: javascript, html

Following code logs a value 0 to 100 in console with 1000ms delay in between. But it does not update DOM element div.innerHTML as intended. How to change DOM element value by JS loop with delay. Looks like setTimeout does not work in loop.

**HTML file**

```
<div id="output"></div>


<script>
var obj=document.getElementById("output");

for(var i=0;i<100;i++){
obj.innerHTML=i.toString();
(function(i){
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log(i);
  }, 1000 * i)
 })(i);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Try assigning to `innerHTML` *inside* the loop, else the loop won't affect the HTML.

Comment: Inside the `setTimeout` callback, but yeah. ^

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your `innerHtml` inside of the `setTimeout`

```js
var obj = document.getElementById('output');

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      obj.innerHTML = i.toString();
    }, 1000 * i)
  })(i);
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

---

You can use of a `setInterval` also

```js
var obj = document.getElementById('output');

var i = 0;

var descriptor = setInterval(function() {
  obj.innerHTML = i.toString();

  i += 1;

  // When it changed the value 100 time, stop the loop
  if (i === 100) {
    clearInterval(descriptor);
  }
}, 1000)
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```